# Get repeating groups with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have string like that:

```
base | text1: 0.01 | text2: 0.02 | text3: 0.03
```

And I need to extract first word and all other text-number pairs.
So this result I expect:

```
("base", "text1", "0.01", "text2", "0.02", "text3", "0.03")
```

I trying this regexp:

```
r"^(\w+)(?:\s+\|\s+)(?:([\w\s]*)\:\s([0-9.]+)(?:\s+\|\s+)?)+$"
```

But it captures only the last text-numberr pair:

```
("base", "text3", "0.03")
```

Here the full code I use:

```
import re

sr = "base | text1: 0.01 | text2: 0.02 | text3: 100.1"

pattern = r"^(\w+)(?:\s+\|\s+)(?:([\w\s]*)\:\s([0-9.]+)(?:\s+\|\s+)?)+$"

result = re.findall(pattern, sr)

print(result.groups())
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could split on `(?: \| |: )` https://regex101.com/r/yhybbS/1

Comment: You shouldn't be surprised that only the last capture values are preserved: that's how regular expressions work. It's a task for two regexes: match all `base` clauses with their tails, then process the tails with a second regular expression. Splitting it, as is sugested in the comment above, is one of the ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to get the desired result is to split on either a space pipe space or colon space.

```
(?: \| |: )
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yhybbS/1)

Example code

```
import re
 
s="base | text1: 0.01 | text2: 0.02 | text3: 0.03"
print(re.split(r"(?: \| |: )", s))
```

Output

```
['base', 'text1', '0.01', 'text2', '0.02', 'text3', '0.03']
```

---

Another option could be using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and make use of the `\G` anchor and capturing groups, where the first word is in group 1, and the pairs are in group 2 and 3.

```
(?:^(\w+)|\G(?!^))\s+\|\s+(\w+):\s+(\d+\.\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ofvzu/1)

Comment: I don't think in this direction :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

```py
import re

sr = "base | text1: 0.01 | text2: 0.02 | text3: 100.1"

pattern1 = r"^(\w+)((?:\s+\|\s+[\w\s]+\s*:\s*\d+\.\d+)+)$"
bases = re.findall (pattern1, sr)

for base in bases:
    result = [base[0]]
    pattern2 = r"\|\s+([\w\s]+)\s*:\s*(\d+\.\d+)"
    texts = re.findall(pattern2, base[1])
    for text in texts:
        result.append(text[0])
        result.append(text[1])      
    print (result)
```

Note the simplified regular expressions.